# Comma delimited string to variables in Python 2

Tags: python

I am looking to take a list or string that when printed looks like this:

```
9532167,box,C,5,20
```

and assign each comma delimited value to a set variable like so:

```
var1=9532167
var2=box
var3=C
var4=5
var5=20
```

(note-this isn't code, but how I want the pieces of string to be assigned to the variables)

Currently I have:

```
var1, var2, var3, var4, var5 = mystring
```

but get this error:

```
exceptions.ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

I realize it is a very simple question, but no amount of searching has turned up something I can understand. I'm a newb to Python.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: You seem to have your assignments reversed: `var1=9532167`, etc.

Comment: Do you mean `var1=9532167; var2='box'; ...`? What you've written there is not remotely legal Python (for instance, integers can't be names). We don't have enough information to answer your question without guessing at what you want.

Comment: I have updated to clarify. Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to split the string.

```
number, type, identifier, height, width = mystring.split(',')
```

Read [more here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

Here, `split` would return a `list` of the individual elements from the string split on `,`

Demo:

```
>>> x = "9532167,box,C,5,20"
>>> x.split(',')
['9532167', 'box', 'C', '5', '20']
>>> number, type, identifier, height, width = x.split(',')
>>>
```

Comment: This does what I was looking for. Thank you for the good explanation despite my poor description.

Answer (score 0):

You need to split the string on `,`:

```
number, type, identifier, height, width = mystring.split(',')
```